# Just installed and 1st time user needs link to novice site?

Tags: software-installation

A good friend just installed a new hardrive in my daughters old Toshiba Satellite L355D, which she passed on to me. I'm retired and looking to expand my old age horizons. This friend gave me a disc witb Lumbuntu 14.04.2 on it to download to is new hardrive. I've done that part and accepted/loaded all the updates the system asked for. 
The most computer experience I've had was with Windows Vista and 7 at the job I retired from. I do have an iPhone and an Android Kit Kat tablet that I manage to use fairly well. I'm looking for some basic, low tech oriented instructions for this Lumbuntu OS. Preferably something I can access and read from my tablet? This friend was really exited for me to start using this OS. He said its lite weight and made for beginners like me.

Comment: The question is too broad, without knowing what you do with your computer, and how you do it. Think of a series of tasks you want to accomplish and search for those in this site. If you can't find any answers, ask a separate question for each task.

Comment: Just looking for a site that lays down the basic operation on Lumbuntu. I'm not familiar with any Linux/umbuntu/lumbuntu stuff at all. Never heard of it before this. They put out help sites for "dummies" for everything else it seems but I can't find a site like that on Google. I'm not afraid to admit I'm one of the aging tech dummies, but I'm reaching out for your help, not your condescension. If there is not such site, so be it. If I'm not up to standards required to ask a question on this site, then I'll gladly remove my ignorance from your membership.

Comment: You are most welcome here. I am not being condescending. Without knowing what you want to do, it is hard to answer your question. See https://launchintolinux.wordpress.com/2012/04/04/getting-to-know-lubuntulxde/ and https://launchintolinux.wordpress.com/2012/04/04/ six-things-to-do-after-installing-lubuntu/ for some ideas about how to get around the system and what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the official forums to be helpful:

http://ubuntuforums.org/index.php

Particularly the New to Ubuntu and General Help subforums for asking questions if you need help with something.

Just mention that you're using Lubuntu (the official website is lubuntu . net)

Depending on what tasks you use your computer for you may find Linux (specifically Lubuntu) very similar, or surprisingly different. One of the first things you might notice is that the method for installing software that you need is quite unlike windows. Here's a quick guide on some differences:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Setup#Coming_from_Windows

Hope some of that helps. As someone who uses Linux for both work and home uses, for the majority of the time it's just Windows with fewer fiddly bits (no antivirus, no defragging, no crap cleaning, sane networking and configuration, unbelievably fewer crashes etc).

Comment: And take a look at http://planet.ubuntu.com/ and Full Circle Magazine http://fullcirclemagazine.org/